# Homebrew PHP5.6 memcached installation error

Tags: homebrew

I'm trying to install the memcached extension for PHP 5.6 via Homebrew.

```
brew install php56-memcached
```

The error I get is

```
Error: No such file or directory - /usr/local/opt/igbinary/include/igbinary.h
```

I've tried reinstalling php56-igbinary and php56 itself. Neither fixes this problem. I tried to locate any files named igbinary.h and could not find any on the computer. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You try remove and reinstall these pakage

```
brew remove php56-igbinary php56-memcached 
brew reinstall php56 --enable-maintainer-zts --build-from-source php56-igbinary --build-from-source php56-memcached --build-from-source
```

Comment: Worked for me using php54

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me with php56-redis with the same error message.
brew reinstall --enable-maintainer-zts --build-from-source php56-redis

php56-igbinary is used from installation location when installing from source